# how to find clients that meet the same criteria in one column

Tags: oracle

I have a column that is like this:

| Client ID | Service Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | housing |
| 122458 | transportation |
| 125837 | education |
| 125837 | transportation |
| 173947 | Childcare |

I am trying to extract data from an Oracle database for all clients who have accessed education and transportation services only. Could anyone please help me write my query?

I have created a Where statement in my query that goes like this:

```
where ch.service_name IN ('education', 'transportation)
```

however, this query gives me all clients who have accessed education and or transportation when in fact, I only want data for clients who have accessed both education and or transportation.

thank you

Comment: I supposed `and or` is a typo and you need `and` between those service names, ain't it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need a `HAVING` Clause along with `GROUP BY` after restricting to only those two `service_name` such as

```
SELECT ClientID
  FROM t
 WHERE service_name IN ('education', 'transportation')
 GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT service_name) = 2
```

**EDIT**(*depending on the comment*) : One option would be converting the query into the one which contains a `COUNT()` analytic function such as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT t.*, COUNT(DISTINCT service_name) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID) AS cnt      
  FROM t
 WHERE service_name IN ('education', 'transportation')
)
SELECT *
  FROM <the_other_table>
  LEFT JOIN t2
 WHERE cnt = 2
```

in order to combine with your current query as desired.

Comment: I have a huge query that is pulling data from multiple tables, is there a way to create a subquery to get this information?

Comment: of course, but need to specify what exactly you want by editing the question @ops_mltsd

Comment: something like this maybe? LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM caseheaders where service name IN ('education' and (SeLECT * FROM caseheaders where service name IN ('transportation'))  - the only reason I ask is because embedding a sub query into the existing query would be much easier for me

Comment: sorry I am not very advanced with sql, could you explain this "over partition by" function?

Comment: Hi @ops_mltsd . [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) calculate an aggregate value based on a group of rows and return multiple rows for each group. During that aggregation, an **analytic clause**, which defines the columns for grouping next to **PARTITION BY**, and ordering logic of the values of the listed columns next to **ORDER BY** clause, takes place within parentheses following some clauses such as **OVER** or **WITHIN GROUP**